# Initial Welcome Message(Banner) after SSH not letting commands to get executed properly

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, ksh

I am trying to `SSH` to a server and the execute some commands on destination server.

Below is my code

```
!/bin/ksh

ssh user@pass <<EOF
how to wait ?

DIR_INPUT=/home/

LOGS=
echo "Enter Deployment Date (YYYYMMDD e.g 20150631)"
read DDATE
DDATE=`echo $DDATE | sed s/[^0-9]*//g`
echo "$DDATE"
MGT=`echo "$DDATE" | cut -c5-6 2>/dev/null`
DGT=`echo "$DDATE" | cut -c7-8 2>/dev/null`
LEQ=`echo ${#DDATE}`

echo $MGT
echo $DGT
echo $LEQ

if [ "$MGT" -gt 12 ] || [ "$DGT" -gt 31 ] || [ "$LEQ" -gt 8 ] || [ "$LEQ" -lt 8 ] || [ "$MGT" -eq 0 ] || [ "$DGT" -eq 0 ]
then
                echo "INVAILID DATE"
                exit 1
fi
echo "$DDATE"
cd $DIR_INPUT
EOF
```

After `SSH` to server there are some predefined text that echoes on server and because of that,the commands associated with `SSH` executes before the terminal of other server comes.

Is there any way to put command which will wait for sometime until the ssh connection is not fully made?

Comment: use [tag:expect]. It does exactly what you want and there is a lot of questions about it.

Comment: expect is not working on my unix
is there any other way to do it ? like using sleep command or anything else ?

Comment: You will probably have to install (on local computer) it if you want to have it working.

Comment: Sorry , but i don't have access to install it,
is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running ssh with the `-T` option to prevent it from allocating a TTY on the remote system:

```
ssh -T user@pass <<EOF
...
```

TTYs are normally used for interactive sessions. If your session on the remote system doesn't have a TTY, the remote system may not send this text.